# Can Hyper-V Server run on Windows XP 32-bit with a 64-bit processor?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-xp, hyper-v, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am trying to get a Virtual Instance of Windows 2008 R2 running from my laptop.  My laptop has a 64-bit processor and is running 32-bit Windows XP.  I have hardware [DEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention) and hardware virtualization (though I don't really know what these mean).

I tried Virtual PC but it cannot run a 64-bit guest OS.  I tried the free VMWare Server, but it does not work from Windows XP.  (I tried several different install configurations before giving up on that one).

So I am down to [Hyper V Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#Microsoft_Hyper-V_Server).  Can it run on a 64-bit processor that has a host OS that is 32-bit?  Is there a way to get a virtual instance of Windows 2008 R2 (on Windows XP) in a different way?  (Preferably free or using Microsoft Products.)

Comment: Why do you need 2008 R2 on your laptop?  Could you just install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a server working on XP 32 bit.

I downloaded and installed VMWare Server Version 1 (Version 2 would not work on XP for me).

I then installed Windows Server 2008 R2 RC x64 as a guest os (I had to tell VWMWare Server that it was going to be a Windows Server 2003 x64)

It seems to be working just fine.

Vaccano

Answer (score 9):

Well for a start HyperV is a server 2008 role, and so will not run on XP at all. The bare metal version still becomes the core OS, and isn't hosted by a guest OS.

VMWare workstation will host 64bit guests on a 32bit OS though.

Answer (score 1):

As JP has said you can't have a 64-bit guest OS running on top of a 32-bit host OS with Hyper-V, however this blog post seems to suggest that it is possible using VMWare.

One suggestion if you really want to get a Hyper-V Server is perhaps to go the ther way, ie. setup Hyper-V Server as your host and then create a VM with Windows XP.

Edit: As this post suggests (in the title only) using another machine or dual-booting may be your only options, after all testing a Virtaul Machine 'Server' inside another Virtual Machine does sound a bit odd...

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is either a Windows 2008 role, or available standalone (I think of it as Hyper-V Core). It's an operating system in its own right, and will not run on top of Windows XP.

Microsoft's virtualization products (Virtual PC, Virtual Server and Hyper-V) don't currently support running 64-bit guests on a 32-bit host, although certain editions of VMWare software do.

In short: you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

i can confirm that if

- you have a compaq elitebook 8730w (intel centrino duo 2 vpro)
- turn on virtualization technology on in the BIOS
- run windows xp (32bit) as your OS

you *can* run windows server 2008 64bit as a guest OS, using VMWare workstation 7.0.0 build-203739

i have done this so i can run sharepoint 2010 beta on my company laptop for hosting the corporate intranet and extranet (only kidding, for demos!)

Virtual PC will not work!  Hyper-v is useless to me...

tristian o'brien

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

Comment: Not a true statement.

Answer (score 0):

Hyper-V is Windows 2008 server feature only and there is no 32-bit version of 2008 server so you won't be able to do what you want.

Comment: True that there is no 32 bit version of Windows Server 2008 R2 (though there is one for the plain Windows Server 2008).  Either way, I am talking about the Hyper V Server, which is a separate product from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I also found Microsoft Virtual Server 2005 R2 SP1 (with the update) that will run Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score -1):

No.  They hypervisor that runs the guest OS runs on top of the host OS.  You can't have a 64-bit guest OS running on top of a 32-bit host OS.

Comment: Reading links like this makes me think that it is possible in theory at least (this link is for VMWare Server 1)  http://communities.vmware.com/thread/149794

Comment: +1 @Vaccano, I am running both 64 and 32bit OSs on a VMWare server

Comment: I am sure VMware can do this, I assume Hyper-V can too.

Comment: This answer is just plain wrong!

Comment: It's right, but only from a certain point of view.  Type I hypervisors *are* the host OS.  If the hypervisor was 32-bit then you couldn't run 64-bit guest OS.

If you install anything with a bypervisor, like VMWare Server, then your former host OS is now the management OS for the hypervisor, not truly a host any more.